# Replace history entry in NextJs app with router.replace

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

We are developing a React/NextJs app and we have the following scenario:

1. The user comes to a "Results" page (`www.oursite.com/results?someKey=1234-abcd`) with certain offers, and clicks an offer
2. A "Redirect" page opens(`www.oursite.com/redirect?someKey=1234-abcd`), with an information that the user will be redirected to our partner. The redirect should happen automatically after 5 seconds or when a button is clicked. After this page, the user leaves our site and goes to our partner's site (`www.ourpartner.com?someKey=1234-abcd`). For this scenario, we are using plain JS timeout and `window.open(redirectUrl, '_self')` method.
   3.If the user clicks the Back button, they get back to the Redirect page. But instead of that, we would like to have them jump back directly to the Results page (`www.oursite.com/results?someKey=1234-abcd`).

I tried using the `replace` method from the Next router, since I understood that will *replace* the current page (Redirect page) with :

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();
router.replace(redirectUrl);
```

...but for some reason, when the user clicks Back on our partner's site, they return to the Redirect page again, and not to the Results.

What am I doing wrong? Can the Next router be used at all to achieve this? Is there another way?

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.replace(newUrl)`?